# MSSQL Deadlock when update withc (updlock)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, database-deadlocks

I got deadlock while updating. The transaction level is set to `Read Committed`. How to avoid deadlock in such situation?

In other cases `WITH (NOLOCK)` and `WITH (UPDLOCK)` helped.
I got the following `T-SQL` query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DEBTORS_CUSTOMERS WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DebtorId = @DebtorId AND ClientFCCustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber)
        UPDATE DEBTORS_CUSTOMERS WITH (UPDLOCK) SET StatusId = @StatusId WHERE DebtorId = @DebtorId AND ClientFCCustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO DEBTORS_CUSTOMERS (DebtorId, ClientFCCustomerNumber, StatusId, DocId) SELECT @DebtorId, @CustomerNumber, @StatusId, @DocId
```

And here is the deadlock I got:

```
   <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594105692160" dbid="63" objectname="EOTestDataGenerator.dbo.DEBTORS_CUSTOMERS" indexname="PK_DEBTORS_CUSTOMERS" id="lockdf8abb00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594105692160">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process3f59048" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processbdbfa088" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594105692160" dbid="63" objectname="EOTestDataGenerator.dbo.DEBTORS_CUSTOMERS" indexname="PK_DEBTORS_CUSTOMERS" id="lockdf5ab200" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594105692160">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processbdbfa088" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process3f59048" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
```

Comment: Why are you using NOLOCK here? In fact, why are you using it at all? Table hints in general should be avoided but the code you have here is a recipe for a deadlock. You are explicitly ignoring any locks on the table and then trying to update the row. That means if something else has a lock on that row you are trying to update it. Remove those table hints and your query will fix itself.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: You are processing multiple rows per transaction, right? This should not deadlock for one row (you might get double-writes, though, which is a bug).

Comment: Change `(NOLOCK)` to `(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` and remove the UPDLOCK from the UPDATE statement.  Then wrap the block in an explicit transaction.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for hint I changed NOLOCK in select statement for UPDLOCK and it seems to work. I got a lot of issues with deadlocks in my app. NOLOCK and UPDLOCK helped to solve them. Without table hints I got deadlock almost every time while updating same record on database. In my case double-writes won't be a bug.

Comment: @DanGuzman the statement is already in transaction. But transaction is set from the C# code in `TransactionScope` and the transaction level i set to Read Committed.

Comment: I would suggest that if you are "fixing" deadlocks with table hints that you are fixing the symptom and not the problem. However, I am glad you were able to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are processing multiple rows per transaction, right? This should not deadlock for one row

You might get double-inserts, though, which is a bug. Two sessions might conclude that there is no row and then both will insert.

There are two ways to make this safe:

1. Issue the select `WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` which is a well-known lock hint sequence. It takes a lock that stabilized the data you are operating on. After this statement has run you have the data for yourself. You can then insert or update. You can also collapse all three statements into one `MERGE` but you still need the lock hints. Also, you must have some kind of global order in which you issue the writes. Right now no matter how you lock there can always be a deadlock if one session writes A, B and the other writes in order B, A. An easy way to get a global order is to issue all writes in a single `MERGE` statement. The query processor usually picks a plan that enforces order.
2. Use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation with retry on deadlock.

Comment: When I used second solution I got deadlock again. The first one seems to work at this moment. Thanks all you guys!

Comment: The point of the 2nd solution is to continue to have deadlocks but retry them. That can be an quick and effective solution.

Comment: But isn't there a risk that there will be endless deadlock? Session A and B won't retry again and again to share the same resources?

Comment: For every resolved deadlock there is exactly one session that lives and makes progress. Progress is guaranteed.

Comment: I have checked second solution. Seems to work perfectly. And there is less to change on Stored Procedures. What is your opinion about setting isolation level to Read Committed? Won't be faster than Serializable?

Comment: The locking hints override the isolation level here. It does not matter.