# Transaction was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have running a concurrent SQL job to update the data in the same table. Which is making deadlock on the server-side. I have tried the locking method which does not solve my problem.

Comment: do those jobs need to be running at the same time?

Comment: When you state: "the locking method", could you clarify exactly what you tried?

Comment: Both Store procedure I am using WITH (NOLOCK) for were ever doing select statement against the table and While updating using WITH (UPDLOCK)

Comment: @Sundaresan - Your situation sounds very similar to what is being discussed here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460027/mssql-deadlock-when-update-withc-updlock

Have a look there, and see whether the suggested workaround there solves your issue.

Comment: To solve deadlocks you need to undestand what each of the processes are doing, and in which order they are acquiring locks -- and does the locking happen in the table or in an index. With the data you've provided there's not much anyone can do. Things like TABLOCKX or HOLDLOCK can solve the problem but that might kill your performance.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I  have solved the issue with the below query. Select  *  from tablename WITH (NOLOCK)     update tablename WITH (UPDLOCK) set column name =''